# How can I extract the numpy value mentioned in tensor

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, tensor

Consider the following tensor...

`tot_fam=rand(1230)`
`TK=tf.math.floor(tf.size(tot_fam)/52)`

The output of this snippet is
 `<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=23.0>`

How can I extract the length, i.e., 23.0 ?

Comment: Try either `tensor.numpy()` or `tensor.eval()`.

Comment: tensor.numpy() worked for me